# xmlReader Failed with: TypeError: Cannot call method 'text' of undefined

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, parse-platform, httprequest

I am using the npm xmlreader to parse my xml I am receiving from yahoo weather on parse's cloud. I have been using the examples from the git repository and the example here: https://www.npmjs.org/package/xmlreader to try to see if I can get the contents of any node at this point and I am having no luck.  I am doing it as such:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("getPage", function(request, status) {
var response = "I never get set";
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    url: 'http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2442047&u=f',
    success: function (httpResponse) {
        console.log("Got here yo");     
        response = httpResponse.text;
        response = response.toString();
        response = parseXML(response);
        status.success(response.toString());
    },
    error: function (httpResponse) {
        status.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
    }
});

});

function parseXML (p1)
{ 
   var xmlreader = require('cloud/xmlreader.js');
   xmlreader.read(p1, function (err, xmldata) {
   if(err) return console.log(err);
   console.log( xmldata.title.text() );
  });
  return "hello";
}
```

every time I run the job I get the error.

Failed with: TypeError: Cannot call method 'text' of undefined

```
<title>Yahoo! Weather - Los Angeles, CA</title>
<description>Yahoo! Weather for Los Angeles, CA</description>
<language>en-us</language>
<lastBuildDate>Thu, 10 Jul 2014 10:47 am PDT</lastBuildDate>
<ttl>60</ttl>
```

I have imported everything correctly and installed it correctly.  If I just call xmlreader.text() it won't fail but there will be nothing to print is it not reading the xml properly? Any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not navigating the nodes correctly.  I was missing a node when trying to access the title I was just trying to do res.title instead I needed to do res.rss.title.